# SQL Server: capitalize first letter of each word without using function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any suggestions on to how to capitalize only the first letter of each word in a cell with select statement - without using a function? I do not have permission to create functions/views/tables in the database, so I need to run a query/select statement automated in a batchjob with OGR.

I can only find examples where the first letter of the whole cell is capitalized OR solving the issue with a function.

It concerns a name-column with strings like:
`'JOHN DOE'`
`'JOHN JANE-DOE'`
`'JOHN-JANE DOE'`
`''`
`'JOHN'`

Comment: If you don't have proper permissions in the database, then you should do this on the application side.

Comment: Even if it was a sensible idea to do this in the database layer, I hope you realise the complexity of what you are asking?  Proper case-ing names is not as simple as 'Capitalise the first letter'.  Names such as `O'Neill` or `McDonald` will not play nicely.

Comment: Even if you do get proper permissions, you still probably want to do this in something other than SQL - there are solutions using pure T-SQL but they'll likely not perform very well.  You could even consider creating an SSIS package that's invoked instead of your SQL statement.

Comment: I worked for a company that tried this once.  We received a number of complaints, including one from a Mr Mcdonald, who was deeply offended by the additional capital letter we added to his surname.  It was much more trouble that it was worth.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Sadly, in this case I have absolutely no other options than using my "Select"-permission in SQL Server - due to company policy. So the only way I know of, to make a monthly dump of data (data is updated every day with no history), is to automate a batchjob on our server using ogr2ogr to call a sql and make a dump.

Comment: @DanField I might not be aware of the degree of the complexity. My sql-skills are limited and I'm new to stackoverflow so I might have asked my question in the wrong way?

Comment: @embr . . . Although this might seem easy to you, it is not a very SQL'ish thing to do.  As you can see by John's answer, there is a way to do it, but simple would not describe the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Name varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'JOHN DOE'),
(2,'JOHN JANE-DOE'),
(3,'JOHN-JANE DOE'),
(4,''),
(5,'JOHN'),
(6,'PATTY O''BRIAN'),
(7,'OLD MCDONALD')


Declare @Str varchar(max) = (Select ID,Name=Lower(Name) from @YourTable for XML Raw)
Select  @Str = Replace(@Str,MapFrom,MapTo)
From  (
        Select MapFrom=P+C
              ,MapTo  =Upper(P+C)
         From (Select * From (Values ('"'),(' '),('-'),(' O'''),(' Mc')) P (P)) A
         Cross Join (Select Top 26 C=Char(96+Row_Number() Over (Order By Number)) From master..spt_values) C
         Union All 
         Select * From (Values (' MC',' Mc')) P (MapFrom,MapTo)
    ) A
Declare @XML xml = cast(@Str as XML)
Select ID   = r.value('@ID','int')
      ,Name = r.value('@Name','varchar(50)')
 From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
 Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ID','Active')
```

Returns

```
ID  Name
1   John Doe
2   John Jane-Doe
3   John-Jane Doe
4   
5   John
6   Patty O'Brian
7   Old McDonald
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm new to Stackoverflow and I was not aware of the degree of complexity of this question.

I found a workaround for now - the company that provides our database infratructure provides an additional table that has the correct formatted names. So I've joined the correct formatted names on the table that I'm working with.

Thank you for the help.